# Index supertype by key of subtype in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following code:

```
type Foo = { foo: string }
type Bar = { bar: string }
type FooAndBar = Foo & Bar 

function fn<T extends Foo | Bar>(list: Array<T>, key: keyof T, acc: FooAndBar) {
    for (const elem of list) {
        acc[key] = elem[key] // ERROR: Type 'keyof T' cannot be used to index type 'FooAndBar'
    }
}


const foos:Foo[] = [{foo: "a"}, {foo: "b"}]
const bars:Bar[] = [{bar: "x"}, {bar: "y"}]

const acc: FooAndBar = { foo: "", bar: "" }
fn(foos, "foo", acc)
fn(bars, "bar", acc)
```

I run into a compilation error `Type 'keyof T' cannot be used to index type 'FooAndBar'` on the line commented above. What type constraints can I add to make it typecheck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example I assume, that you want to accumulate the latest elements of each array in the common `acc` variable.

In this case you can make `fn` more generic:

```ts
function fn<T>(list: Array<T>, key: keyof T, acc: T) {
    for (const elem of list) {
        acc[key] = elem[key];
    }
}
```

So you can pass any array, and the only requirement for acc is to be of the same type as the items.

Here's a full [Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=21&pln=20&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKAzBAuKBnYAJwEsA7AcygF8BYAKFEigCEBDQ5NKAI3dwJIVq9RtHhwAgqQAmbDinFQAZC3b16GAK6kAxsGJxSmUgB4AKgD4AFABtiBXBMKFWIcxYA0UANYQQuXxA4DCgzL1YdHVwzAEo0eihEzDgOKx1DAigIGwgAWyhgqDsCONQEpIqInQBtQIBdTmy82r86gG5yxNo6bvUGcGgAaT88TkDCq0UAH1VCGI7%20pmGQPAAmMb9C6Z9NkLkF%20nTSTKw4PFxxaoaUavRT3AAiVgfqLzucKAfuF6o6w4zgDx2OdZldOLcgYRHgAPH5vSGPEA-P50f7HQFVC4IKSydicd5wR4PLy8KGfH5ovBwHIAOhscHIVgA5FUmeFIvMNKQrKc8F4HqdiVAqjFKdSIHSGczTgBaVnsnScugYbmkvmfUlCkVi2n0xlM0lyyJs4UctpAA)

Your example code cannot work because your `key` parameter is of type `keyof (Foo | Bar)` is `never`: i.e. `Foo` and `Bar` have no keys in common